# angular translate static-loader-file PascalPrecht

Tags: angularjs

I´m using Angular-translate (PascalPrecht module).

I successed to make it work according to the example in: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-translate.html

However, I would like to have all my translations in different json files using loader-static-files, but this is not working for me. I´m not sure I´m doing right here.

In my angular module I just replaced the code working (now commented) with the loader-static call:

```
angular.module('myApp.i18n', ['pascalprecht.translate'])
    .config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
        /*$translateProvider.translations('en', {
            HOME: 'Home',
            COMPANIES: 'Companies',
            WHAT_TO_DO: 'What to do',
            ABOUT: 'About us',
            CONTACT: 'Contact'
        })
        .translations('es', {
            HOME: 'Inicio',
            COMPANIES: 'Empresas',
            WHAT_TO_DO: 'Qué hacer',
            ABOUT: 'Nosotros',
            CONTACT: 'Contacto'
        });*/
        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('es');

        $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
          prefix: '/languages/',
          suffix: '.json'
        });
}]);
```

I have added to my app folder the files:

/app/languages/en_US.json
 /app/languages/es.json

When I load my home site, I see next error in console:

```
http://localhost:1234/languages/es.json 404 (Not Found)
```

If I remove the first '/' in my prefix, like this:

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
              prefix: 'languages/',
              suffix: '.json'
            });
```

Then, I get next error in console:

Unexpected token H

Sorry, I think I don´t undertand how this should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that your server sends the `.json` as json and not as plain text.
Also, make sure that the names for the .json files depend on the corresponding language key.

As you can read here: http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading ("Using staticFilesLoader")

The code looks good to me, so once you've fixed the issue that your server isn't sending json as json, things should work.

Comment: Mmmm not sure this is the problem. Please, pay attention at the URL the server is requesting: http://localhost:1234/languages/es.json 404 (Not Found). However if I write next url in my browser: http://localhost:1234/app/languages/es.json I get a json file as: [
    {
        HOME: 'Inicio',
     COMPANIES: 'Empresas',
     WHAT_TO_DO: 'QuÃ© hacer',
     ABOUT: 'Nosotros',
     CONTACT: 'Contacto'
    }
]. I think the problem is that it is not finding the resource because it is skipping /app.

Comment: Then just add 'app/' to the prefix :)

Comment: hehe not so easy again: if I add prefix: 'app/languages/', then I get this strange error: GET http://localhost:1234/app/app/languages/es.json 404 (Not Found) . Note there are two app. And If I add: prefix: 'app/languages/' Then I get: SyntaxError: Unexpected token H

Comment: Again, make sure your server sends json, this is why the unexpected token error occurs.

Comment: Sorry, and thanks for th patient, I don´t know how to confirm if the server is sending the data as json instead as plain text. I just can say when I type http://localhost:1234/app/languages/es.json in my browser I get:     {
        HOME: 'Inicio',
     COMPANIES: 'Empresas',
     WHAT_TO_DO: 'QuÃ© hacer',
     ABOUT: 'Nosotros',
     CONTACT: 'Contacto'
    }     How can I confirm this?

Comment: url ` http://pascalprecht.github.io/angular-translate/docs/en/#/guide/10_asynchronous-loading#usingstaticfilesloader` not available :(

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it. As Pascal said in the comments, the problem was that the json file had a wrong format. You have to put all the values between double quotes.

The path was right.