# How to separate messages from templates into separate file in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I need to separate messages-labels (like 'Hello there!') into separate file for easier managing.

I found that I can use angular-translate to solve it but I cannot figure how to make it working.

```
<script src="path/to/angular.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/angular-translate.js"></script>

angular.module('angularTranslateApp', ['pascalprecht.translate'])
.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
// Our translations will go in here
}]);

app.config(function ['$translateProvider', ($translateProvider) {
$translateProvider.translations('en', {
HEADLINE: 'Hello there!',
INTRO_TEXT: 'And it has i18n support!'
});
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
}]);
```

In templates:

```
<h2>{{ 'HEADLINE' | translate }}</h2>
<p>{{ 'INTRO_TEXT' | translate }}</p>
```

**Can you show how I can move this mesagges-labels into separate json file?**

**And how can I include that json file into the code?**

Answer (score 0):

Can you Check the below urls:

[angular translate static-loader-file PascalPrecht](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358610/angular-translate-static-loader-file-pascalprecht)

http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-translate.html